# Apache User Permissions

Tags: permissions, nginx

I am trying to Create a permission set for my nginx Web Application as below;

OS: ubuntu
nginx User: www-data

www-data user's primary group: manage

```
# su www-data -
$ groups
manage
```

Path to Webroot: /var/www/html/website
website's permission: [740] I even try giving it [770]

```
ls -ltr /var/www/html
drwxrwx--- 15 admin manage  4096 May  8 21:01 website
```

when I browse my application: it says;

[image]

I want my user 'admin' has Read / Write / Execute permissions on Webroot, while webuser (www-data) does not have write or execute.

Comment: Add the output of `namei -mo /var/www/html/manage`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, open up the nginx.conf file with:

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

and find this field:

```
user www-data
```

change *www-data* to the user you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But what I want to do is without changing the nginx user, just by giving nginx user's group enough permissions to run the webserver.

What I am trying to achieve is that I have a user called : admin,
who can read/write/execute files in webroot, while web user can only read files in webroot.

how do I Do this? is it not possible?